# SCIP Executable for Pyomo

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, pyomo, ampl, scip

I wish to use the SCIP solver with Pyomo to solve a MILP non linear problem as it is one of the fastest solvers out there.
But when I set the solver as "scip" in SolverFactory function of the library, I get an error saying "scip" executable not found.

I understand that to use any solver, we need to have it's executable in the PATH. 
I have tried different solvers like Bonmin, Couenne. Their executable were readily available to download from the AMPL webstie itself but I was not able to find the SCIP executable (don't know why is that, since it is opensource)

Following this, I tried researching into making my own SCIP executable and stumbled upon this link: http://www.zverovich.net/2012/08/07/using-scip-with-ampl.html

But the instructions are for linux! So if someone could direct me into the direction of a scip executable or instructions for how to build a scip executable for windows then it would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that SCIP is free only for non-commercial/academic use.

Answer (score 2):

You can download SCIP executables/installers for different platforms here:

https://scip.zib.de/#download

See section "Executables" for precompiled files including the AMPL interface.

<strike>According to the [AMPL documentation](https://ampl.com/products/solvers/all-solvers-for-ampl/), SCIP is not officially supported anymore.</strike>

A better alternative is to use [PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt): You should be able to formulate your models in a very similar fashion, including nonlinear constraints, and you avoid having to write out the model to a file and read it back in with the solver.

Comment: On that page, choose a SCIP/AMPL executable. For Windows, that is currently only available for SCIP 5: https://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=scipampl-5.0.1.win.x86_64.intel.opt.spx.exe.zip

Comment: Hi, I followed the link and downloaded the executable but when I added it to the path and tried to access the interface,nothing was happening. So I guess the is not the right executable file.

Comment: Hi, So i followed the install guide and I see that SCIP Optimization Suite needs to be installed in order for the library to work. Is there anyway to get my hands on the scip executable without having to install the suite? On a separate question, after installing the Suite, I will get a scip.exe file (which I think is the executable file i am looking for originally), so can I just take this file and use it with Pyomo. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The SCIP/AMPL executable should work without installing any SCIP Optimization Suite. Maybe you need to rename it to scipampl.exe, I don't know what Pyomo exactly expects. "nothing was happening" is not really a useful error description that we could help on. There is now a SCIP/AMPL executable for SCIP 6 on Windows, too: https://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=scipampl-6.0.0.win.x86_64.intel.opt.spx2.exe.zip

Comment: It is totally possible to setup SCIP with pyomo as long as the AMPL interface is properly installed. See stackoverflow.com/a/56886542/7382307, stackoverflow.com/a/66736905/7382307 and stackoverflow.com/a/69549587/7382307